# How to Display hints to user when he is inactive for more than 5 sec in unity?

Tags: unity, unityscript

I have made a 2D Game using unity in which user has to select objects of similar color and now i want to display hint when user is unable to select the color for more than four seconds.

I want something similar to candy crush hint displaying system in which candy crush shows hint by highlighting the possible combination if user is not able to identify any combination himself.

I cannot figure out how to find if the user is inactive so that i can display hints.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me in figuring it out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever an action counting as active interaction (tap/successful match) happens, capture current time to a variable in the hint showing script. In `Update()` method check if the difference is greater than delay(seconds).

```
public class HintController : MonoBehaviour {
  public float LastTime;
  public float HintDelay = 5.0f;

  void Start() {
     LastTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
  }

  void Update() {
     if(Time.realtimeSinceStartup - LastTime > HintDelay)
        displayHint();
  }
}

//...when/where tap/match/whatever logic happens, save current time
//hc is reference to the HintController script
//you can assign it, for example, through designer variable or getComponent<> method
hc.LastTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to wondra's solution, you can use OnMouseDown() in Unity to detect both mouse and tap events. So if you were to use:

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    hc.LastTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
}
```

Your timer would reset every time your user taps the screen or, on desktop, clicks the mouse. You can also add to this by adding a collider to the board (or whatever object is containing the *candies*) and using a Raycast to detect whether or not the tap/click is on the board. That way, any taps/clicks that are *NOT* on the board won't reset the hint timer.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a Boolean if player is tapping or touching at the moment.[Touch detection](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html)

If player is not touching the screen start a timer. [Timer with Invoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) or [Timer with Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html)

If timer goes to 5 seconds, enable the hint in a UI text object.

Comment: I cannot recommend a Invoke/coroutine solution - it seems like overkill.

Comment: appreciate it. was being beginner friendly. your's is efficient way. thanks.